# Google Maps is changing the center of map

Tags: javascript, jquery, google-maps, google-maps-api-3

I have a few Google Maps on a page. Only one is shown at a time and you can change from one map to the other by clicking buttons. Since some maps are hidden when Google Maps first initialize the maps, I need to "refresh" the map that is being shown and for that I need to get the center of the map. I use `map.getCenter()` but somehow the center gets changed before getting there.

I have debugged the following code and I know where it gets changed, but the why is still a mystery.

```
function initMaps() {
    if ($('.gmap').length) {
        var $maps = $('.gmap'),
        myOptions = {
            zoom: 16,
            mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP,
            scrollwheel: false,
            mapTypeControlOptions: {
                mapTypeIds: [google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP, 'mapStyle']
            }
        },
        maps = {};

        $maps.each(function () {
            var latitude = parseFloat($(this).attr('data-latitude')),
                longitude = parseFloat($(this).attr('data-longitude')),
                mapNumber = $(this).attr('data-number'),
                baseLatLng = new google.maps.LatLng(latitude, longitude);
            myOptions.center = baseLatLng;
            maps[mapNumber] = new google.maps.Map(this, myOptions);
            var mapCustomType = new google.maps.StyledMapType(mapStyle, myOptions);
            maps[mapNumber].mapTypes.set('custom', mapCustomType);
            maps[mapNumber].setMapTypeId('custom');
        });

        $('.map').hide();
        $('.map:first').show();
        console.log(maps);  // Centers are the same
        changeMaps(maps);
    }
}

function changeMaps(maps) {
    console.log(maps); // Centers are the same
    $('.maps-list span').click(function () {
        console.log(maps); // Centers have changed !!!
        var $mapClass = $('.map-' + $(this).attr('class')),
            map = maps[parseInt($mapClass.find('.gmap').attr('data-number'))];
        $('.map').hide();
        $mapClass.show();
        refreshMap(map);
    });
}

function refreshMap(map) {
    google.maps.event.trigger(map, 'resize');
    map.setCenter(map.getCenter());
}
```

In the `changeMaps()`function, the centers of my second map (the one that is hidden at first) changes during the click event of a button that does nothing else but trigger this function). I did remove a couple variables and changed a few class names so that the code is easier to read, so you can ignore any other problems with the code.

I'd like to find out why the center gets changed, but if you have a cleaner way of doing all of this, that would also be great.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This code will not have any effect:

```
map.setCenter(map.getCenter());
```

`getCenter()` returns the current `center` of the map(which will change when you resize the map), not the value that has been set initially.

You must store the initial value in another property and then set the center to the stored value.

in `initMaps()`:

```
myOptions.center = myOptions._center = baseLatLng;
```

in `refreshMap()`:

```
map.setCenter(map._center);
```